# Array of promises two different behaviours

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a code which produces array of promises:

```
    async addDefect(payload) {
    this.newDefect.setNote(payload.note);
    this.newDefect.setPriority(payload.priority);
    const name = await this.storage.get(StorageKeys.NAME);
    const movingFilesJob = this.cachedPhotoUrls.map(url => {
      const defectImage = this.newDefect.generateImageUrl(name);
      return this.file.moveImageToAppFile(url, defectImage.url);
    });
    await Promise.all(movingFilesJob);
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.newDefect);
  }
```

now I would like to move creating of `movingFilesFob`to another class. I wrote the following function:

```
async persistPhotos(photoBuffer: string[], defect: Defect) {
    const name = await this.storage.get(StorageKeys.NAME);
    return photoBuffer.map(url => {
      const defectImage = defect.generateImageUrl(name);
      return this.file.moveImageToAppFile(url, defectImage.url);
    });
  }
```

but when i try to replce the code I am getting following error:

Argument of type 'Promise[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<{} | PromiseLike<{}>>'.   Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'Promise[]>'

Iam calling the new function as below:

```
async addDefect(payload) {
    this.newDefect.setNote(payload.note);
    this.newDefect.setPriority(payload.priority);
    const name = await this.storage.get(StorageKeys.NAME);
    const movingFilesJob = this.photo.persistPhotos(this.cachedPhotoUrls, this.newDefect);
    await Promise.all(movingFilesJob);
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.newDefect);
  }
```

How come the same code in first example is working but in the following example is not. I could asing type :any to return but it is not working in runtime anyway.

Comment: How are you calling `persistPhotos`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly answering this question:

***How come the same code in first example is working but in the following example is not. I could asing type :any to return but it is not working in runtime anyway.***

Because you inadvertently changed the return type.

Original:

```
const movingFilesJob = this.cachedPhotoUrls.map(...)
```

This assigns an array to `movingFilesJob`.

Refactor:

```
return photoBuffer.map(...)
```

returns an array of Promise objects from `persistPhotos()` while the `async` keyword expects it to be a Promise object not an array of them.

T.J. Crowder is always someone to pay attention to: As he pointed out, the simple fix is to await the promises from the map thus:

```
const movingFilesJob = await this.photo.persistPhotos(this.cachedPhotoUrls, this.newDefect);
```

Comment: I didn't take your comment as in any way negative, for the avoidance of doubt. :-) And no reason to apologize. Good answer!

Answer (score 3):

Move `Promise.all` inside the function

```
async persistPhotos(photoBuffer: string[], defect: Defect) {
    const name = await this.storage.get(StorageKeys.NAME);
    return Promise.all(photoBuffer.map(url => {
      const defectImage = defect.generateImageUrl(name);
      return this.file.moveImageToAppFile(url, defectImage.url);
    }));
  }
```

`Async` function always returns a single Promise. Now you are returning an array of Promises. Because of that the result of this function is a single Promise returning an array of Promises:

`const results = await persistPhotos(...);`

now `results` will contain array of Promises. If you want to get their results you have to:

`const realResults = await Promise.all(results);`

or, you can move `Promise.all` inside the function.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to return an array of promises from an `async` function. Just as with any other non-promise value, the function will return a promise of that array.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `async` will convert anything returned into a single Promise, so array of Promises will be converted to a Promise returning array of Promises. But I guess filemonczyk wanted to get an array of results, not a Promise returning array of Promises, so I wanted to provide him solution to his problem. With `Promise.all` inside this function, now it will work the same way it worked for him before the refactor.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Unless you absolutely need it, I would recommend to return a promise for an array of results instead of a promise for an array of promises. Putting the `Promise.all` inside the function is much cleaner.

Comment: @Bergi - I don't agree, but it's certainly one option (now that the OP has shown how `persistPhotos` is being called, and hidook has corrected their answer). Moving the `Promise.all` just moves more logic into `persistPhotos`, leaving the code calling it less in control.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, my point is just that very rarely you need that additional control. With a promise for an array of promises you almost always would do `const results = await Promise.all(await …)`, and there's no point in doing that at every call site. (Also the more deeply nested type is more confusing, as the OP's mistake shows)